# How to highlight the matching cell of selected cell in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

As title, I want a function that highlights "A" cells when I click one of "A" cells and highlight "B" cells when I click one of "B" cells. Like what I showed in the image. I've surveyed before but still don't know how to do it. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: [This documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) should help you, but as I've seen on other questions and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147016387?pli=1), some triggers may no work properly on V8 script editor.

Comment: You could also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289045/format-highlight-multiple-cells-based-on-value-selected-in-one-cell-in-google-sh?rq=1)'s method as reference. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a custom script in your spreadsheet file using the [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) simple trigger function.

You just need to [create a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) in your spreadsheet file & then copy/paste this sample script below:

***SCRIPT:***

```
function onSelectionChange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var selectedValue = sheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
  var selectedColumn = sheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation().toString()[0];
  var totalRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

  for(row=1; row<=totalRows; row++){
    var checkValue = sheet.getRange(row,sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn()).getValue();
    //Check if the selected cell value has matches on the column then highlight them
    if(selectedValue == checkValue && selectedColumn == selectedValue){ 
      sheet.getRange(row,sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn()).setBackground('#b7e1cd');
    }
  }
}
```

***SAMPLE RESULT:***

> Sample sheet with data:

[image]

> Once the script has been saved, after selecting "A" cell on Column A, "B" cell on Column B & "C" cell on Column C, all matched cells per column were automatically highlighted:

[image]